Importing texture button from spritesheet in Godot 4
I have a spritesheet with all my buttons, and would like to use individual sprites as my buttons, not the entire sheet. Is there a way to do this? (I am a complete beginner)
I tried putting the file into the "normal" texture and it popped up with my spritesheet. I had expected it to allow me to crop or select a certain frame, as it does with other sprite nodes, but it did not give the option (as far as I am aware)

You sould use an AtlasTexture to be able to crop the spritesheet

Create a new atlas texture in the texture section of the button
Drag your spritesheet in
You can then click the button Edit region below to crop it

